# Преобразование SVG в XML Drawable

Tags: android, svg, android-drawable

Есть иконка в SVG. На [сайте](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) преобразовал ее в XML Drawable формат Вот что получилось

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="500dp"
    android:height="500dp"
    android:viewportWidth="500"
    android:viewportHeight="500">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#50AE32"
        android:pathData="M56.7,34.7 C56.7,34.7,63,46.7,58.4,55.8 C53.8,64.9,44.2,99.1,47.6,113.9
C51,128.7,63,127,63,127 S78.4,77.5,75.5,63.2 C72.7,48.9,71.5,45,56.7,34.7 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#3D8533"
        android:pathData="M61.9,41.8 C61.9,41.8,69.4,51.1,68.6,58.3 C67.7,65.6,61.9,82.1,61.9,82.1
S69.4,72.2,69.7,71.4 C70.1,70.6,77.3,50,61.9,41.8 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#50AE32"
        android:pathData="M51,120.5 C51,120.5,49.3,73.8,25.4,76.1 C1.5,78.4,12.3,97.7,18.6,93.8
C24.9,89.8,18,84.7,18,84.7 S22.6,77.3,28.3,79.6 C34,81.9,37.4,81.9,41.4,92.7
C45.4,103.5,48.8,125.2,48.8,143.4 C48.8,161.6,59.1,162.2,59.1,162.2 L51,120.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#51AE32"
        android:pathData="M250.1,5.5 C385.41,5.5,495.1,115.19,495.1,250.5
C495.1,385.81,385.41,495.5,250.1,495.5 C114.79,495.5,5.1,385.81,5.1,250.5
C5.1,115.19,114.79,5.5,250.1,5.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#3D8534"
        android:pathData="M250.1,17.6 C378.948,17.6,483.4,122.052,483.4,250.9
C483.4,379.748,378.948,484.2,250.1,484.2 C121.252,484.2,16.8,379.748,16.8,250.9
C16.8,122.052,121.252,17.6,250.1,17.6 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="url(#SVGID_1_)"
        android:pathData="M250.1,28.7 C372.818,28.7,472.3,128.182,472.3,250.9
C472.3,373.618,372.818,473.1,250.1,473.1 C127.382,473.1,27.9,373.618,27.9,250.9
C27.9,128.182,127.382,28.7,250.1,28.7 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fillAlpha="0.24"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.24"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M252.5,38 C202.5,38,156.6,55.5,120.6,84.8 C141.6,97.6,165.7,114.8,190.8,137.6
C265,205.2,207.3,282.8,308,330.7 C349.8,350.6,408.9,338.3,454,304
C459.1,286,461.8,267,461.8,247.3 C461.8,131.7,368.1,38,252.5,38 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#F7EC67"
        android:fillAlpha="0.53"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.53"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M198.6,56.5 C157.7,68,100.2,93.2,82.2,165 C64.3,236.8,164.8,236.8,268.9,229.6
C373,222.4,434,269.1,437.6,208.1 C441.2,147.1,350,13.8,198.6,56.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M237.2,66.9 C237.2,66.9,176.2,95.6,237.2,106.4
C298.2,117.2,326.9,102.8,326.9,102.8 S311.2,47.9,237.2,66.9 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M345.7,98.5 C345.7,98.5,332.5,102.9,343.5,111.7
C354.5,120.5,357.7,138.4,372.6,128.4 C387.4,118.3,363.3,96.3,345.7,98.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#EFE528"
        android:fillAlpha="0.53"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.53"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M55.4,340.4 C55.4,340.4,93.7,421.7,194.1,443.2
C294.5,464.7,219.2,468.3,186.9,457.5 C154.6,446.8,86.4,419.3,55.4,340.4 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#3D8533"
        android:pathData="M354.6,457.2 C354.6,457.2,374,434.3,379.5,415.8
C379.9,414.3,380.3,412.9,380.5,411.5 C383.9,392.4,403.7,380.8,411.2,389.7
C418.7,398.6,405.7,408.1,403.7,402 C401.7,395.9,406.4,394.5,406.4,394.5
S398.2,387,390.7,396.5 C383.2,406.1,378.4,425.2,378.4,428.6
C378.5,431.9,365.5,451,354.6,457.2 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#50AE32"
        android:pathData="M408.5,417 C408.5,417,391.6,427.6,384.6,436 C377.6,444.4,367.7,456.2,361.9,459.4
C356.1,462.6,350.3,465.9,350.3,465.9 S347.5,445.4,350,436.9
C352.5,428.4,364.1,416.1,367.7,415.1 C371.4,414.2,382.5,408.6,387.7,409
C392.8,409.4,408.5,417,408.5,417 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#3D8533"
        android:pathData="M387.3,406.5 C387.3,406.5,372.8,423.6,371,429.9
C369.2,436.3,351.4,463.5,351.4,463.5 S357.8,459,364.6,448.9
C371.4,438.9,385.5,413.9,388.2,411.2 C391,408.6,390.4,405.8,387.3,406.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#7AB929"
        android:pathData="M349.9,461 C349.9,461,349.7,428,366.2,420.1 C382.6,412.2,392,428.1,405.7,429.4
L420.6,429.4 C420.6,429.4,413.7,416,411.7,410 C409.7,404,395.6,403.7,387.4,406.5
C379.2,409.2,362.5,408.9,353.3,421.1 C344.1,433.2,345.5,460.1,349.5,464.6
C353.4,469,349.9,461,349.9,461 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#7AB929"
        android:pathData="M350.4,465.8 C350.4,465.8,383.3,436.6,393.1,442.6
C402.9,448.6,412.7,451.6,412.7,451.6 S382.6,463.6,372.1,466.7
C361.5,469.7,350.4,465.8,350.4,465.8 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#7AB929"
        android:pathData="M353.2,464.4 C353.2,464.4,343.4,447.8,330.6,447.1
C317.8,446.3,306.5,438.1,306.5,438.1 S318.5,466.7,329.1,469
C339.6,471.2,354.7,470.4,353.2,464.4 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#50AE32"
        android:pathData="M414.9,424.9 C414.9,424.9,407.6,413.7,401.5,411 C397,409,393.4,407,389.2,406
C388.6,406.2,387.9,406.3,387.4,406.5 C386.2,406.9,384.8,407.2,383.3,407.5
C386.2,407.4,390.3,407.8,395.2,409.9 C405.3,414.3,414.9,424.9,414.9,424.9 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#E9E207"
        android:pathData="M385.9,411.5 C385.9,411.5,364.5,409.4,356.6,419.8
C348.7,430.1,362.8,413.6,376.6,415.3 C390.4,417,398,422.5,405.2,424.3
C412.5,426,398.4,412.9,385.9,411.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#50AE32"
        android:pathData="M316.3,447 C316.3,447,320.8,453.6,328,458 C335.2,462.5,350.2,465.8,350.2,465.8
S329.4,471.2,316.3,447 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#50AE32"
        android:pathData="M361.3,456.8 C361.3,456.8,362.6,456.2,364.9,455.4
C368.4,454.2,374.2,452.7,380.7,452.7 C391.4,452.7,406,450.7,406,450.7
S391.2,450.4,383,450.4 C374.9,450.4,371.6,450.4,361.3,456.8 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#E9E207"
        android:pathData="M382.1,456.4 C382.1,456.4,370,454.8,363.3,459.2
C356.7,463.6,370.4,464,382.1,456.4 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#E9E207"
        android:pathData="M324.4,449.1 C324.4,449.1,336.1,449.1,340.5,452.7
C344.9,456.3,346.2,460.4,346.2,460.4 S333.3,462,324.4,449.1 Z" />
</vector>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в этом файле есть строка:

```
android:fillColor="url(#SVGID_1_)
```

Т.е. где градиент он проставил такую надпись. Можно вручную как-то вместо этой строки указать что будет заливаться градиентом?

Comment: Можно это сделать вообще или никак?

Comment: градиент в векторах поддерживается только с api 24+, так что никак.

Answer (score 1):

Градиент в векторах поддерживается только с api 24+, так что никак.
Тут лучше нарезать в png иконки.

Comment: понял, спасибо.